# Create required number of groups using linq groupby (whithout while, for, foreach)

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a task like this:
Write a LINQ expression that shows how many books have been printed in each decade of the last century.
The answer should be given as a sequence of objects with properties: D - decade number (1, 2, ... 10), C - number of books. And also you cannot use while, for, foreach.

There is a class

```
class Book {
    public string Title { set; get; }
    public int Year { set; get; } }
```

and a collection of books - `books`

In the beginning I did this:

```
var g = books.GroupBy(b => b.Year % 100 == 0 ? (b.Year == 1900 ? 1 : 10) : (b.Year % 100 - 1) / 10 + 1,
        b => b.Year,
        (decade, years) => new
        {
            D = decade,
            C = years.Count()
        });
```

But this only creates groups for existing decades from the collection, then i realised that there must be 10 groups with a D value from 1 to 10. I tried to do this, but without loops, it did not work for me. Could you tell me how this can be implemented in a group-buy, since the tasks are related to the introduction to the linq, but I could not figure it out properly.

P.S. Sorry for bad English

Comment: first of all, if you look at the date is the year 2021, that means, that the last century is not starting at 1900, but 2000, so you only need 3 decades

Comment: Sorry I put it a little wrong, I meant the previous century

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we can create *all* `10` decades (to be sure that each decade is present in the answer even if there are no books printed in it)

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
```

and then `Count` the books in them. So, given a collection, enumeration of `books`

```
  IEnumerable<Book> books = ...

  var result = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 10)
    .Select(D => new { 
      D = D + 1,
      C = books.Count(book => book.Year >= 1900 + D * 10 && 
                              book.Year < 1900 + (D + 1) * 10)
    });
```

Comment: Didn't work very much with enumerable. Thank you!